# Append Non-Editable String to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there anyway to append a String to an EditText value, so that the string appended is not editable?

i.e. Say I have an EditText for Email Addresses, I want to treat an email address as a single entity rather than single characters. Therefore if a users deletes the last character of the email address, I want the whole email address to be removed rather than the last character.

I've been looking at Spannable but can't see anything obvious. This is similar to how Gmail and other apps do it.

Comment: Maybe you can just have a text changed listener and then manually modify the contents of the EditText, then replace it with what you want. If the user entered me@sample.com then when the length decreases by 1, set the text to an empty string. Don't know if that is what you want though. :)

Comment: @Zarah: Good answer (I upvoted it :-). Maybe you should have put it like an "Answer" instead of a "Comment", though. As it is now, there doesn't seem to be a way for Chris Banes to accept your solution as "The Answer" (provided he wants to, of course).

Comment: @dbm Hey, thanks! :) I wasn't sure if that was what Chris Banes wanted. Seems like a lot of people agreed with me, so re-posting it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer (and modifying the words to make my suggestion clearer).

Have an [`onTextChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int, int)) 
attached to your `EditText` to be notified of user input.  You can then check the length of the contents of the `EditText`, and if it decreases by 1, then you can assume that the user deleted a character.

If the user entered `me@sample.com` then on your `onTextChanged`, you can set the text to an empty string.  Of course you would have to do some checking first to make sure that the user has entered a complete email address before applying your change.  Like, maybe make sure the user has entered the `@` character already, or there is space after the last non-space character.